# Ajax script to pass the variables a php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm a newbye about Ajax and I have a problem  with my first script.
My intention was to pass the variables of a form to a php page and display the result in a div of the same page.

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Organazier 1.0</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" />
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <h1>Test 1.0</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" />
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <form class="MyForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="link">link</label>
                        <input type="link" class="form-control" id="link" name="link" value="Value1" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Categoria">Categoria</label>
                        <input type="Categoria" class="form-control" id="Categorie" name="Categorie" value="Value2" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Titolo">Titolo</label>
                        <input type="Titolo" class="form-control" id="Title" name="Title" value="Value3" />
                    </div>
                    <button id="newDownload" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" />
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
                <h2>Result:</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" />
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" name="MyResult" id="MyResult" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" />
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
    <script src="dist/js/ajaxform.js" />
</body>

</html>
```

The ajaxform.js script is the following:

```
$(function() {
//twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#newDownload").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
            url: "response_normal.php",
            data: $('form.MyForm').serialize(),
                success: function(msg){
                      $("#MyResult").html(msg)  
                },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
                }
                });
    });
});
```

Could you help me please to find out the problem?

Thank you very much,
Pazzeo

Comment: Is the request executed ? See the network tab on developer tools/firebug to see the result (if executed).
use async:"false" in your ajax/jquery request (if true, often causes the request being cancelled). Use the developertools/firebug to see if there's no something wrong in your js syntax (in your request or any other place).

And as @Dagon just asked, please be more specific in your question.

Comment: its a requirement of a question that you attempt to debug it yourself, you should be able to narrow down the area, especially important when mixing languages

Comment: Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug (for Firefox) is your friend here. The network tabs in both tools should tell you about any AJAX requests and what the result is.

And as above, where is the PHP code? Does it actually work? Assuming the AJAX requests are functioning it could be the PHP to blame.

Answer (score 0):

Make async false in Ajax and it'll work. I tested it on my server just to make sure and it turned out to be the problem.

```
$(function() {

$("button#newDownload").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
        url: "response_normal.php",
        async:false,
        data: $('form.MyForm').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                  $("#MyResult").html(msg)  
            },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
            }
            });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well your script seems right, I recommend that: show your .php maybe the wrong isn't in your script, but try this:

```
$(function() {
//twitter bootstrap script
$("#newDownload").click(function(){ // Im only change this line
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "response_normal.php",
            data: $('form.MyForm').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                  $("#MyResult").html(msg); // and this the semicolon  
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
                }
            });
});
```

});

If you are new in AJAX like me I recommend use firebug, is an extension for firefox and you can see what send ajax, what receive php and what return php

Answer (score 0):

when you want to make submit the form using Ajax ,you must stop form submit default action before using ajax [using preventDefault() method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Ex:

```
$(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("#newDownload").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "response_normal.php",
                 data: $('form.MyForm').serialize(),
                 success: function(msg){
                       $("#MyResult").html(msg);  
                 },
                 error: function(){
                       alert("failure");
                 }
            });
     });
});
```

To test ajax action and response for ajax  use `network` tab into `Developer tool for chrome`  or `net` tab into `firebug with firefox`